# Paso de hashmap a Fragment

Tags: java, android

esta es mi primera consulta.

Hace poco que he empezado con Android, por lo que os pido disculpas si pensais que la pregunta es muy básica.

Estoy desarrollando una app en la que quiero que a partir de una lista, al pulsar en los items se abra una activity con dos fragments, uno muestra un mapa y el otro la información sobre el lugar.
La lista la he hecho con su String[] y su arrayAdapter y la llamada a la Activity con sus fragments es correcta. El problema lo tengo para pasar los datos a los dos fragments.

Para ello he creado el objeto:

```
public class llistalocals {

        private String ordre;
        private String nomCiutat;
        private String nomClub;
        private String direccio;
        private String numTelf;
        private String latitut;
        private String longitut;


    public llistalocals(String ordre, String nomCiutat, String nomClub, String direccio, String numTelf, String latitut, String longitut) {
        this.ordre = ordre;
        this.nomCiutat = nomCiutat;
        this.nomClub = nomClub;
        this.direccio = direccio;
        this.numTelf = numTelf;
        this.latitut = latitut;
        this.longitut = longitut;
    }
```

con sus getters, setters y toString

y un Hasmap que funciona como un repositorio de todos los datos:

```
package com.example.dracnegre;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class repositoriLocals {

    private static repositoriLocals repo_loc = new repositoriLocals();
    private TreeMap<String, llistalocals> lltaloc = new TreeMap<>();

    public static repositoriLocals getInstance() {
        return repo_loc;
    }


    private repositoriLocals(){

        saveLoc(new llistalocals("1","Alaquas","C.A. Alaquàs","xxx","xxx","39.3970134","-0.4138396,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("2","Alborache","C.A. Alborache Piccadilly","xxx","xxx","39.3929035","-0.7743851,14"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("3","Aldaia","C.A. Aldaia Educart","xxx","xxx","39.4606223","-0.4596357,18"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("4","Alzira","C.A. Alzira","xxx","xxx", "39.1491082","-0.4405458,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("5","xxx","xxx","39.4727535","-0.389589,13"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("6","Benimaclet","C.A. Gambito-Benimaclet","xxx","xxx","39.4810591","-0.3545263,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("7","xxx","xxx","39.4170123","-0.7888384,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("8","Burjassot","xxx","xxx","39.5053766","-0.4078544,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("9","Ciutat Vella","C.A. Ciutat Vella","C/ Paseo La Pechina 42. 46008 VALENCIA", "626816690","39.475888","-0.393696,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("19","Dama Roja","C.A. Dama Roja","xxx","xxx","39.4612416","-0.3666761,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("20","Gandia","C.A. Fomento de Gandia","xxx","xxx","38.9658895","-0.1829014,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("21","Massanassa","C.A. Massanassa","xxx","xxx","39.4110476","-0.401376,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("22","Mislata","C.A. Mislata Lanjarón Discema","xxx","xxx","39.47524","-0.411274,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("23","Moncada","C.A. Moncada FDM","xxx","xxx","39.5458423","-0.3946106,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("24","Monserrat","C.E. Montserrat","xxx","xxx","39.3564934","-0.5997589,14"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("25","Quart","C.A. Ajedrez Quart","xxx","xxx","39.4780371","-0.4225869,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("26","Torrefiel","C.A. Torrefiel","xxx","xxx","39.4867701","-0.3737708,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("27","Xativa","C.E. Xátiva","xxx","xxx","38.9893469","-0.5274009,17"));
        saveLoc(new llistalocals("28","Xeraco","C.A. Xeraco","xxx","xxx","39.3843647","-0.2402383,8"));
    }


    private void saveLoc(llistalocals lead) {
        lltaloc.put(lead.getOrdre(), lead);
    }

    public List<llistalocals> getLeads() {

        return new ArrayList<>(lltaloc.values());
    }
}
```

Aunque he cambiado HashMap por TreeMap, porque he visto que este último ordena, pero no sé si implica alguna diferencia más.

La cuestión es que quiero pasar los datos a los fragments. Al de mapas, latitut y longitut y al de datos todos los demás, pero no sé como hacerlo.

Tengo dos tipos de dudas:

1) de Concepto: no sé si se puede hacer con un Adapter que funcione igual que con ListView pero en lugar de Lista con fragment. O hacer un Bundle con sus put para poner los datos y con sus get para rescatarlos. Pero me despista mucho que los datos cambian según el item pulsado y no sé como montarlo ni donde.

2) la segunda es propiamente de programarlo una vez sepa cual es el método que he de utilizar. Con esto también se aceptan ideas, que a veces fallo en cosas y no sé si es por el método o por la programación.

Gracias por anticipado por vuestras respuestas.

Comment: No hace falta que hagas un adapter, lo correcto seria pasarlo en un bundle, pero claro seria engorroso pasar dato por dato, para no caer en eso lo mejor es serealizar los datos, para eso solo tendras que hacer serealizable tu clase llistalocals y ya estaras en condiciones de pasarlo a un fragment o activity. Publica la respuesta correcta cuando lo logres por favor.

Comment: Ok, Gracias. Eso queria saber, si adapter o budle. En cuanto lo tenga lo subo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Me ha costado un poco resolverlo, no he encontrado aquí la ayuda que esperaba.
Hacer un Bundle no es posible, ¡porque estoy en un fragment! y sólo se puede en una activity.

La solución a la que he recurrido es usar SQLlite. He creado una classe

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
```

donde he metido todos lo datos y en el fragment los he leido con un Cursor

```
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT nomCiutat, nomClub, direccio, numTelf, latitut, 
longitut FROM Poblacions WHERE nomCiutat='" + nomCiutatTriada + "'", null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            ciutat.setText(c.getString(0));
            club.setText(c.getString(1));
            direccio.setText(c.getString(2));
            telf.setText(c.getString(3));
            paslat=c.getDouble(4);
            paslot=c.getDouble(5);
            pasClub=c.getString(1);
        }
```

Paso los datos al layout y listo

```
    ciutat = root.findViewById(R.id.nomCiutat);
    club = root.findViewById(R.id.nomClub);
    direccio = root.findViewById(R.id.adreçaClub);
    telf = root.findViewById(R.id.numTelf);
```

En definitiva, la cuestión se ha quedado por resolver (pasar un hashmap a un fragment) lo que he hecho es cambiar de estrategia para conseguir el mismo objetivo con otro método (SQLITE en lugar de HASHMAP).